# S.M.A.R.T Power_On_Hours wrap around with Seagate Baracuda?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a well used Seagate Barracuda 7200.9 with 80 GB. The smart report shows

```
 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       5646
```

But that can't be right. 5646h is only 235 days or less than eight month. The sister disk, a Seagate Barracuda 7200.10, shows:

```
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       90427
```

This is plausible: The 90427 hours is 10.3 years. I remember the server has been setup in 2009 and at that time the hardware was not new.

So I assume that the 7200.9 has experienced an overflow of the hour counter and has restarted at some point at 0. Does anybody know at what hour that would be? What is the internal time unit used to count uptime? And what variable type is used to count those?

Comment: Does it really matter?

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to one of my server disks recently:
ST2000NM0033 (Seagate Constellation ES.3 2TB)

SMART record (previous day):
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   011   011   000    Old_age   Always       -       78177

SMART record (next day):
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   011   000    Old_age   Always       -       13

So it jumped from 78177 hours to 13 hours the next day ...